# Should I have two package.jsons for a node.js website using Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a simple website using Node.js and Express.js with a typical root-level `package.json` to handle my dependencies.

Now, I'm learning to use Google Firebase for web hosting and functions to deploy the website. Upon executing the Firebase CLI command `firebase init functions`, I now have a `functions` directory that also has a `package.json` file. I transferred my initial `/app.js` file into the `functions/index.js` and it's working fine when I `firebase serve` for testing.

Here is my project directory structure:

```
functions
└─views
└─index.js
└─package.json <- contains firebase-admin and firebase-functions dependencies
public
└─images
├─styles
└─scripts
firebase.json
package.json <- contains express, handlebars, etc. dependencies I had originally created.
```

Is it good practice to now have 2 `package.json` files for this project? One for Firebase functions, and the other for my app? Should I consolidate them into one, and if so, which one?

I'm still new to back end development, so any advice would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to see your `functions` as your backend server. In the end if you host your web app and call your `functions` via http requests your `functions` act as independent "components" even then they are in the same place in your local project. That's why they need their own `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

To help rookies like me, yes you should have two package.json files.

One for your front end. One for your Firebase Functions 'backend'

To install packages on the functions `package.json`, in the terminal navigate to the functions folder.